# android studio dos not show GUI xml designing after update

Tags: android-studio

[image]

i did an update of android studio or android studio plugins and the ide stopped showing xml view designer and the component tree thinks that there's nothing to show.
i tried to sync and rebuild and clean the project and to restart the ide and it still dose not solve the problem.
this is not the first time it happens to a project and i can't work more on the xml view of that project
what can i do to solve the problem ?
thanks

Comment: Close android studio or restart pc

Comment: i closed the ide and for previous times i restarted the pc and it did not help

Comment: close project and reopen it again

Comment: it dos not help